# Response value in noCaptcha reCaptcha always false

Tags: php, recaptcha

My goal is to use google's "noCaptcha reCaptcha" mechanism to verify, if the user is a human on a contact form for a website. I am not a very experienced web developer, so I had to look up several tutorials on PHP and POST-methods.

I now got it working to the point, where I do get a response from google, but the value for the "success" element returned by the POST request is always false, even though the graphical element on the webpage says it is fine. The error code returned by the same request is "NULL", which I guess is a good thing.

Am I misunderstanding something here? All research on this specific error only turned up cases, where either the response value was not assigned or there has been an error message of some kind.

I use google's API ([link to the used API](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/1.0.0/php/recaptchalib.php)) for reCaptcha here, because attempts at sending HTTP-Request objects and using curl flat out did not work. In the first case I guess it is because of missing libraries and in the second case "response" always got a "NULL" value assigned (or rather no value, because this was the default).

In the following code parts, `$secret` is the secret key from google, `$response` is the code sent by the captcha, gotten from `$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]`. The mail code itself works perfectly fine, I tested it seperately before.

```
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);

if ($response) {
  $answer = $reCaptcha->verifyResponse($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], $response);
} else {
  echo "There has been an error with the authentication";
}

var_dump($answer);

if ($answer != NULL && $answer->success) {

  $err = mail($recipient, $subject, $mailtext, implode("\r\n", $headers));

  if ($err == false) {
    echo "The mail could not be sent.";
  }

  echo "The E-Mail was sent.";

} else {

echo "Your identity could not be verified.";

}
```

Comment: I assume you have $response = $_POST['response'] somewhere in your code, or your PHP has register global variables to on?

Comment: More like $response =$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"], but yes.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: No I haven't solved it yet.

Answer (score 1):

The code should be:

```
if ($answer != NULL && $answer->success) {
```

As per the [example](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/blob/1.0.0/php/example-captcha.php#L54)

Comment: While this was an error, it did not solve the issue, as var_dump clearly states, that answer->success is false.

Comment: What is the var_dump of $answer? Can you post the response?

Comment: object(ReCaptchaResponse)#2 (2) { ["success"]=> bool(false) ["errorCodes"]=> NULL }

Comment: I'm assuming that as there are no errorCodes then you can rule out the errors listed here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify. This now points to a genuine false validation, so I'd look at making sure the  $response variable contains the value.

Comment: When I var_dump $response, I geht a (462) string looking like this: [...]kIh_MGbkNGM3fS8q0Q9_8jMBmb7lRtxYh-Y_S7AhjzfCYahGdNMC27SBxbRc1yvlIIzuXQClVRBl[...]

Comment: I suggest the following: 1) Download the example from here https://github.com/google/recaptcha/tree/1.0.0/php and see if that works after entering your siteKey and secret. 2) Make sure the domain is listed on the settings here: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

Comment: I can try that tomorrow. About the domain: I did register my domain name correctly, but this website is only accessible over 'subdomain.domain.de/department' . 'subdomain.domain.de' produces an access error because this is a university server and the administrator restricted it this way. Might that be a problem?

Comment: As long as the sub domain is listed in the domains list when editing the reCaptcha key then that will be fine.

Comment: Ok, I tried using the example now, and the problem is exactly the same. The example website is 'http://fachschaft.stud.uni-saarland.de/physik/captcha_example.php' and the registered domains are:fachschaft.stud.uni-saarland.de
stud.uni-saarland.de
uni-saarland.de

Answer (score 0):

its because you are running it on your local host, go to recaptche settings page on Google, and add a new profile with domain: localhost

Do not forget to change the sitekey and secret once you add the new profile.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried, what you suggest, but it did not help. If I register a new Key with localhost, the captcha field on the website now says 'ERROR: Invalid domain for site key'. This does make sense, in my opinion, because the website is not hosted on localhost. Any other ideas?

Comment: double check that you have set these somewhere before loading recaptchalib.php, also try to clear cache and free the session
 // your secret key
$secret = "6Lc2XxQTAAAAAJxy5eXXXXXXXXXvx";
 
// empty response
$response = null;
 
// check secret key
$reCaptcha = new ReCaptcha($secret);